# Saclar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql

I have tables as

```
Cust1

+----+------+-------------+
| ID | Name | Referred_id |
+----+------+-------------+
|  1 | aaa  |             |
|  2 | bbb  |           1 |
|  3 | ccc  |           2 |
|  4 | ddd  |           2 |
|  5 | eee  |           4 |
+----+------+-------------+
```

```
Invoice

+-----+--------------+---------+
| ID  | billing_date | cust_id |
+-----+--------------+---------+
| 101 | 01-02-2017   |       1 |
| 102 | 01-03-2017   |       2 |
| bbb | 01-04-2017   |       3 |
+-----+--------------+---------+
```

I need the output as

```
+-----+--------------+-----------+---------------+
| ID  | billing_date | cust_name | referred_name |
+-----+--------------+-----------+---------------+
| 101 | 01-02-2017   | aaa       |               |
| 102 | 01-03-2017   | bbb       | aaa           |
| bbb | 01-04-2017   | ccc       | bbb           |
+-----+--------------+-----------+---------------+
```

```
Select c.id,
i.billing_date,
c.name,
(select
b.name as referred_name
from cust1 a left join cust1 b on a.referred_id=b.id)
from cust1 c, invoice i where c.id=i.cust_id
```

the query above is throwing error as scalar subquery produced more than one element. Can someone plz look into this.

Thanks

Comment: You are getting this error, because your subquery, which is supposed to return one value only, returns more than one row. Unfortunately, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Why does your output contain just one row? Why this row? By what rule do you decide which invoice ID to show? Then, for invoice 102 you show its customer bbb and its referenced customer aaa. What would you show for invoice bbb? Its customer ccc? And its referenced customer bbb? Or would you follow the chain further and show the customer aaa again?

Comment: You haven't tagged your request with your DBMS. Which are you using? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? ... Then, comma-separated joins (`from cust1 c, invoice`) should no longer be used. They were made redundant by explicit joins (`from cust1 c inner join invoice`) in the SQL standard of 1992.

Comment: I have just shown one row as an example, the output will give similar results for all the invoice id's.  I am writing this script in PLX software which is an inbuilt tool of Google, the dialect shows GoogleSQL

Comment: Okay, I've completed the desired output for you. Please edit your request, if this is not what you are after. (I also looked for a Google SQL tag, but this doesn't seem to exists. So I just left the "sql" tag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your subquery is not correlated. In your main query you deal with the tables `cust1` aliased `c` and `invoice` aliased `i`, but in your subquery you are not referencing `c` or `i` at all.

It seems you want:

```
select
  c.id, i.billing_date, c.name,
  (
    select cr.name
    from cust1 cr
    where cr.id = c.referred_id
  ) as referred_name
from invoice i 
join cust1 c on c.id = i.cust_id
order by c.id, i.billing_date;
```

You can achieve the same with an outer join:

```
select c.id, i.billing_date, c.name, cr.name as referred_name
from invoice i 
join cust1 c on c.id = i.cust_id
left join cust1 cr on cr.id = c.referred_id
order by c.id, i.billing_date;
```

Both queries are standard SQL, and very basic at that. I assume them to run in your environment, too.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use Top 1 in your subquery. As you are new I would suggest go through joins and basic SQL.

```
Select c.id,
i.billing_date,
c.name,
(select TOP 1
b.name as referred_name
from cust1 a left join cust1 b on a.referred_id=b.id)
from cust1 c, invoice i where c.id=i.cust_id
```

Comment: Thanks, will go through the basics. This Top statement is not working, its giving syntax error

Comment: Nitu Sharma: This is because `TOP` is a proprietary key word in SQL Server (and maybe one or two other DBMS). It is supposed to limit the rows the subquery returns to one row here. But this is completely arbitrary; you'd just get one customer name the DBMS happens to pick.